Is there a way to integrate Payment Gateway in flutter/dart that would be used to transfer amount to different destination accounts?
I am trying to develop an app that will have all the NGOs, Charity foundations etc in it.
I want to achieve functionality that when a user opens NGO 1 and taps on NGO 1 'Donate Now' button, that would take user to my payment gateway, on that gateway there will be NGO 1 name, info etc.
When user select payment method either by card or apple pay whatever, and taps Pay Now button then the amount will be transferred directly to NGO 1 account.
I would only get a notification that transaction has been made, amount details, transaction number etc.
Basically, i want a payment gateway to let me act as a middle man.
I am still checking out options as my main target for donations, charity is Pakistan and Stripe, Skrill, these are all not available for Pakistan.

Did u find a solution to achieve this??

there are so many payment gateways that supported in flutter some examples are,
Razorpay, Stripe etc.
you can refer the
Razorpay from pub.dev

but is it safe to use RazorPay for making transaction in Pakistan region? Stripe is not available for pakistan or even Saudi Arabia
